# Angular sortBy not sorting page results as expected, why?

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I can't seem to get the angular `sortBy` to work, it doesn't sort data properly.  Sort by price for example doesn't give lowest to highest correctly.  Can anyone see if I'm doing anything wrong?  The data comes back from the backend ordered by price ascending but doesn't display in the correct order.

As far as I can tell I'm doing everything correctly.

Here's a sample of the data I'm trying to sort:

```
[
    {"Inbound":{"SearchWeight":1,"Duration":5100000,"DurationString":"1h 25m","DepartureDateString":"Sunday 05 Jul 2015","DepartureTimeString":"07:50","DepartureTime":28200000,"DepartAirportName":null,"DepartureIata":"GLA","ArrivalDateString":"Sunday 05 Jul 2015","ArrivalTimeString":"09:15","ArrivalTime":33300000,"ArriveAirportName":null,"ArrivalIata":"LGW","Stops":0,"StopData":"Direct","AirlineName":"EasyJet","AirlineThumbnailUrl":"easyjet","GUID":947178494,"TTResultNumber":"4_37.0","StopInfo":[],"FlightExtras":null,"Price":35.14,"CheapestReturn":0,"NumAdults":2,"NumChildren":0,"NumInfants":0,"Selected":false,"Outbound":false,"BaggageIncluded":false,"ArrivesNextDay":false,"FlightNo":"882","PairOutFlightNo":"883"},"Outbound":{"SearchWeight":1,"Duration":5100000,"DurationString":"1h 25m","DepartureDateString":"Saturday 27 Jun 2015","DepartureTimeString":"08:55","DepartureTime":32100000,"DepartAirportName":null,"DepartureIata":"LGW","ArrivalDateString":"Saturday 27 Jun 2015","ArrivalTimeString":"10:20","ArrivalTime":37200000,"ArriveAirportName":null,"ArrivalIata":"GLA","Stops":0,"StopData":"Direct","AirlineName":"EasyJet","AirlineThumbnailUrl":"easyjet","GUID":947178494,"TTResultNumber":"","StopInfo":[],"FlightExtras":null,"Price":35.14,"CheapestReturn":0,"NumAdults":2,"NumChildren":0,"NumInfants":0,"Selected":false,"Outbound":false,"BaggageIncluded":false,"ArrivesNextDay":false,"FlightNo":"883","PairOutFlightNo":""},"Price":70.28,"TTResultNumber":"4_37.0","DepartureDateString":"Saturday 27 Jun 2015"},

    {"Inbound":{"SearchWeight":1,"Duration":5100000,"DurationString":"1h 25m","DepartureDateString":"Sunday 05 Jul 2015","DepartureTimeString":"07:50","DepartureTime":28200000,"DepartAirportName":null,"DepartureIata":"GLA","ArrivalDateString":"Sunday 05 Jul 2015","ArrivalTimeString":"09:15","ArrivalTime":33300000,"ArriveAirportName":null,"ArrivalIata":"LGW","Stops":0,"StopData":"Direct","AirlineName":"EasyJet","AirlineThumbnailUrl":"easyjet","GUID":1816944519,"TTResultNumber":"4_61.0","StopInfo":[],"FlightExtras":null,"Price":35.14,"CheapestReturn":0,"NumAdults":2,"NumChildren":0,"NumInfants":0,"Selected":false,"Outbound":false,"BaggageIncluded":false,"ArrivesNextDay":false,"FlightNo":"882","PairOutFlightNo":"897"},"Outbound":{"SearchWeight":1,"Duration":5100000,"DurationString":"1h 25m","DepartureDateString":"Sunday 28 Jun 2015","DepartureTimeString":"21:20","DepartureTime":76800000,"DepartAirportName":null,"DepartureIata":"LGW","ArrivalDateString":"Sunday 28 Jun 2015","ArrivalTimeString":"22:45","ArrivalTime":81900000,"ArriveAirportName":null,"ArrivalIata":"GLA","Stops":0,"StopData":"Direct","AirlineName":"EasyJet","AirlineThumbnailUrl":"easyjet","GUID":1816944519,"TTResultNumber":"","StopInfo":[],"FlightExtras":null,"Price":35.14,"CheapestReturn":0,"NumAdults":2,"NumChildren":0,"NumInfants":0,"Selected":false,"Outbound":false,"BaggageIncluded":false,"ArrivesNextDay":false,"FlightNo":"897","PairOutFlightNo":""},"Price":70.28,"TTResultNumber":"4_61.0","DepartureDateString":"Sunday 28 Jun 2015"},

    {"Inbound":{"SearchWeight":1,"Duration":5100000,"DurationString":"1h 25m","DepartureDateString":"Sunday 05 Jul 2015","DepartureTimeString":"07:50","DepartureTime":28200000,"DepartAirportName":null,"DepartureIata":"GLA","ArrivalDateString":"Sunday 05 Jul 2015","ArrivalTimeString":"09:15","ArrivalTime":33300000,"ArriveAirportName":null,"ArrivalIata":"LGW","Stops":0,"StopData":"Direct","AirlineName":"EasyJet","AirlineThumbnailUrl":"easyjet","GUID":851384341,"TTResultNumber":"4_53.0","StopInfo":[],"FlightExtras":null,"Price":36.785,"CheapestReturn":0,"NumAdults":2,"NumChildren":0,"NumInfants":0,"Selected":false,"Outbound":false,"BaggageIncluded":false,"ArrivesNextDay":false,"FlightNo":"882","PairOutFlightNo":"895"},"Outbound":{"SearchWeight":1,"Duration":5100000,"DurationString":"1h 25m","DepartureDateString":"Sunday 28 Jun 2015","DepartureTimeString":"19:45","DepartureTime":71100000,"DepartAirportName":null,"DepartureIata":"LGW","ArrivalDateString":"Sunday 28 Jun 2015","ArrivalTimeString":"21:10","ArrivalTime":76200000,"ArriveAirportName":null,"ArrivalIata":"GLA","Stops":0,"StopData":"Direct","AirlineName":"EasyJet","AirlineThumbnailUrl":"easyjet","GUID":851384341,"TTResultNumber":"","StopInfo":[],"FlightExtras":null,"Price":36.785,"CheapestReturn":0,"NumAdults":2,"NumChildren":0,"NumInfants":0,"Selected":false,"Outbound":false,"BaggageIncluded":false,"ArrivesNextDay":false,"FlightNo":"895","PairOutFlightNo":""},"Price":73.57,"TTResultNumber":"4_53.0","DepartureDateString":"Sunday 28 Jun 2015"}
]
```

Here's my `ng-repeat` (the `filter : searchFilter` does not seem to be affecting it):

```
<div data-ng-repeat="flight in filteredResults | filter : searchFilter | startFrom:(currentPage - 1)*10 | orderBy:sortOrder | limitTo:10 " class="flight-results-container">
```

Relevant code from my controller:

```
  $scope.sortOrder = '-Price';

  $scope.filters = [
      { name: 'Price - Lowest to Highest', value: '-Price'},
      { name: 'Price - Highest to Lowest', value: 'Price'},
      { name: 'Duration - Longest to Shortest', value: "-Outbound.Duration+Inbound.Duration"},
      { name: 'Duration - Shortest to Longest', value: "Outbound.Duration+Inbound.Duration"},
      { name: 'Departure - Latest to Earliest', value: "-Outbound.DepartureTime"},
      { name: 'Departure - Earliest to Latest', value: "Outbound.DepartureTime"}
  ]
```

My code the creates the filter option:

```
        <label class="sub-filter--dropdown">
            <span class="sub-filter--title">Sort by</span>
            <select ng-model="sortOrder" class="dropdown-select">
                <option ng-repeat="filter in filters" value="{{filter.value}}">{{filter.name}}</option>
                <option style="display:none" value="">Select A Filter</option>
            </select>
        </label>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I'm hoping to get around to this at the end of the week/early next week.  Looks like your reply may help so sincerely appreciated.  As soon as I can see what's going on with this I'll accept your answer if all goes to plan :)

Comment: @PSL you deleted your answer?

Comment: Thanks for adding that back .... I really do want to get round to it asap ..... things at work have been insane - priorities changing etc .... just the usual crap :(

Comment: @PSL Hey, I've looked at this again.  It looks like there is something else causing this.  The sort works if only one airline is selected in the filter, multiple airlines appears to screw the sort up for some reason.  I'm still looking into it.